# Facing some issue in grpc

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, grpc

**Problem description**

When I am trying to call a grpc request from a grpc client it works well for nearly 30-40 mins but after that time it automatically throws an error about the backend being unavailable although grpc server backend is running fine. after 2-3 failed requests It will automatically reconnect the grpc server and the same case happens again and again

**Reproduction steps**

Create a grpc server, a client with a docker image of 20-alpine and add corn that automatically calls one rest API and that rest API calls the grpc server after 30 minutes it gives a connection error

**Enviourment**

Linux, 5.10.199-190.747.amzn2.x86_64
Node v20 with Kubernetes with AWS ALB
@grpc/grpc-js, v1.9.13 [e.g. gRPC@1.12.0]

if anyone can throw some light.